# Not getting an array as result (calling a webservice by AJAX-JSON)

Tags: php, ajax, json, codeigniter, rest

I'm trying to get the result of my web service as an array and then loop over the result to fetch all of the data; what I have done so far:

In my web service when I return the result I use

```
return json_encode($newFiles);
```

and the result is as following:

```
"[{\"path\":\"c:\\\\my_images\\\\123.jpg\",\"ID\":\"123\",\"FName\":\"John\",\"LName\":\"Brown\",\"dept\":\"Hr\"}]"
```

then in my Web application I am calling the rest web service by the following code in the RestService class:

```
public function getNewImages($time) {
    $url = $this->rest_url['MyService'] . "?action=getAllNewPhotos&accessKey=" . $this->rest_key['MyService'] . "&lastcheck=" . $time;

     $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($data) {
        return json_decode($data);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then in my controller I have the following code:

```
public function getNewImgs($time="2011-11-03 14:35:08") {
    $newImgs = $this->restservice->getNewImages($time);
    echo  json_encode$newImgs;        
}
and I'm calling this `enter code here`controller method by AJAX:

$("#searchNewImgManually").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            datatype: "json",
            url: "<?PHP echo base_url("myProjectController/getNewImgs"); ?>",
            success: function(imgsResults) {
                alert(imgsResults[0]);
            }

        });
    });
```

but instead of giving me the first object it is just giving me quotation mark (the first charachter of the result) "

Why is that? I am passing in JSON format and in AJAX I mentioned datatype as "JSON" !

Please let me know if you need more clarification! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going out on a limb here but I think you need to call `JSON.parse(imgResults)` in the return from your `$ajax( . . .` call. I am guessing that `alert(imgResults[0])` is returning the first character of your json response which is a quotation mark. 
Also note that the json returned is an object and your alert will display "[Object][Object]". You will need to access an individual element of your json:

```
returnObj = JSON.parse(imgResults);
alert("object field is: " + returnObj.path); //or whatever relevant field you need to see to verify
```